# boost::thread_specific_ptr slows drastically relative to simple TlsGetValue and TlsSetValue

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I had a small class called WCThreadSpecificPrivateData.
Its implementation:

```
class WCThreadSpecificPrivateData
{
public:
    WCThreadSpecificPrivateData();
    ~WCThreadSpecificPrivateData();

    void* GetData();
    void  SetData(void*);

protected:
    uint32_t m_DataKey;
};

WCThreadSpecificPrivateData::WCThreadSpecificPrivateData():m_DataKey(0)
{
    m_DataKey = ::TlsAlloc();
}

void* WCThreadSpecificPrivateData::GetData()
{
    void* retVal = 0;

    if (0 != m_DataKey)
        retVal = ::TlsGetValue(m_DataKey);
    return retVal;
}

void  WCThreadSpecificPrivateData::SetData(void* in_data)
{
    if (0 != m_DataKey)
        ::TlsSetValue(m_DataKey, in_data);
}
```

I used it to store pointers to thread specific struct called TargetSpecificData.
At some point I decided to use instead of this class boost::thread_specific_ptr. It works for me, however, I experience drastic performance drop. Everything became much more slower.

I checked boost implementation (For Windows) and saw that it is also implemented with TlsGetValue and TlsSetValue calls, so I expect roughly the same behavior. Can someone suggest what caused such a drop?

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you many ideas "what caused such a drop", largely because you don't show how you use the `thread_specific_ptr`.

Also, consider just using `thread_local` (c++11) as most compilers "roughly" support it now. (There are some minor limitations, mostly with static initialization of non-trivial types). Nothing that cannot be worked around with a lambda-initializer:

```
thread_local std::unique_ptr<my_thing> thing = 
         [] { return new std::unique_ptr<my_thing>(); }();
```

**Update** In fact, there might be a reason: if you are creating many threads (and letting them run to completion) there might be more destructions (`boost::thread_specific_ptr` destructs the contained entity at exit of a `boost::thread`)